# unable to setup powerline for vim

Tags: macos, mojave, vi

I'm new to mac and would like to setup powerline program for terminal and vim. I was able to setup to the bash shell but cannot do it for vim.

I can setup for terminal.

[image]

This is what I've added to .bash_profile file.

[image]

This is what I've added to .vimrc file.

[image]

I'm getting this error when I launch vim

[image]

Comment: Is this vim or macvim? The latter requires a bit more setup.

Comment: how do I know that?

Comment: It should be pretty obvious. It looks like you're launching vim via `vim` so likely plain vim, unless you specifically installed MacVim and aliased (like I did).

Comment: Regardless, why are you trying to set powerline up like that? Powerline for vim is a separate thing from powerline-shell? IIRC you can install it with `pip install powerline-setup`.

Comment: I followed https://medium.freecodecamp.org/jazz-up-your-bash-terminal-a-step-by-step-guide-with-pictures-80267554cb22 to setup powerline for terminal. I would like it for both terminal and vim

Comment: powerline-setup doesn't exist. powerline-status is the correct package and I've installed that. Also, I've followed instructions from https://coderwall.com/p/yiot4q/setup-vim-powerline-and-iterm2-on-mac-os-x now the error is gone but there is no powerline bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88550/discussion-between-kunaguvarun-and-riker).

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the instructions from

[vim powerline mac](https://coderwall.com/p/yiot4q/setup-vim-powerline-and-iterm2-on-mac-os-x)

and powerline is displayed in my vim setup finally. :)

[image]

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant